# NullPointerException trying to show an image in Processing 3.3.7

Tags: image, nullpointerexception, processing, loadimage

I'm new to Processing and I'm studying it using the Processing Handbook. 
I have this example code :

```java
PImage img;

void setUp() {
  size(200, 200);
  img = loadImage("selfportrait_small.jpg");
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  tint(255, 102);
  image(img, 0, 0, 200, 200);
  tint(255, 102, 0, 204);
  image(img, 40, 40, 200, 200);
}
```

When I try to run it I get a NullPointerException in the first call to image(). As you can see in the image below, the jpg file is stored in the data folder:
[Processing project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4y67m.png)

Am I missing something? Is there something wrong I'm not able to see?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you wrote "setUp" and not "setup" :-)
Since setUp() is never called the image is never loaded.

Comment: Oh my goodness... Thank you! That's what happens when you're too tired... :)